# DB type 449900 is not valid

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, informatica

I am able to connect to snowflake via Informatica Powercenter version 10.2 hotfix 2.
And able to list all tables I would like to import to Informatica as target.
But get this error: DB type 449900 is not valid

Suppose I've granted necessary (insert, update, delete ect) options to the table on snowflake also.
Someone may have clue?

Comment: How you are connecting informatica? are you using ODBC driver?

Comment: Not really. I am in Powercenter Designer and use its "Create PowerExchange for Snowflake Target" as to connect to snowflake .

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it:
Problem is due to Informatica powercenter Snowflake plug-in was not registered.
Rutine for plug-in registering for Informatica Powercenter: https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powerexchange-adapters-for-powercenter/10-4-0/powerexchange-for-snowflake-user-guide-for-powercenter/powerexchange-for-snowflake-configuration/registering-the-powerexchange-for-snowflake-plug-in/registering-the-plug-in-from-the-administrator-tool.html